# Center expanding text on a hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a hover working with some text and overlay, but I want the text to be centered in the middle. The heading might change so it needs to be center no matter the number of words (I know there is a limit to the container).

I know this is possible to using jquery but I just wanted to see if there was a CSS way of doing it.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -4px -4px 0;
}
li img {
  display: block;
}
li .over {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
}
li:hover .over {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
      <div class="over">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think Jason Miller's answer is the best for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `line-height` to the height of the container, or you can use the transform trick to vertically center your `<h1>`:

```
li .over h1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;        // 50% of the parent
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);   // -50% of the child
}
```

Source: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it what I fell upon when I was messing around.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -4px -4px 0;
}
li img {
  display: block;
}
li .over {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
li .over p {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
li:hover .over {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wapper">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
      <div class="over">
        <p>Hello by name is stephen motteshead</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```